# RoundRectShape not drawing

Tags: android, canvas, android-shapedrawable

I'm trying to draw a rounded rectangle on a `Canvas` object but nothing is showing up. I initialize the `RoundRectShape` like so:

```
test = new RoundRectShape(new float[]{r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r}, new RectF(100, 100, 100, 100), null);
```

I then call `test.draw(canvas)` but nothing shows up. Why is it not drawing, and did I create the `RoundRectShape` correctly? Because I was quite confused about how I'm supposed to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for `RoundRectShape`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.graphics.Paint)):

> `void draw (Canvas canvas, Paint paint)`
>
> Before calling this, you must call `resize(float, float)`.

If you do not call `resize()`, your shape has no dimensions.

Comment: yes, this worked :). Is there any way that I can set the location of the shape? Because at the moment it is just at 0,0 in the corner.

Comment: @Ryan Not 100% sure since I haven't tried it, but it looks like you can construct a new `ShapeDrawable` using your `RoundRectShape`, then call `setBounds()` on that new drawable, and then draw that drawable to the canvas.

Comment: This set the location but because the `ShapeDrawable` draw function doesn't have a `Paint` parameter, it removes the color of and such from the shape

Comment: Nevermind. I managed to fix the problem by omitting the use of a `RoundRectShape` object at all and using a `Path` instead. Ultimately made things much easier